# Rolling paper with bones

Tags: animation, rigging, export

I'm trying to make rolling paper using bones. I'm using a curve, three bones, and a plane. The bones are following the curve path but the plane which is subdivided does not make the right turn and it also not rolling. How should I achieve this?

[image: screenshot]

I have solved this animation in the way that the *Curve* modifier was directly attached to the mesh, but I'm using Blender exporter which exports only mesh animations using bones and these are my restrictions.

Can somebody please help?

[image]

Regards Jerry.

Comment: Please show you work as a Blender Screen Capture. Please show your weight paint.  Even if you include a file. Some people may not want to open you file because it may not be necessary.

Comment: Armature Tutorial .... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvG39bGEsKI

Answer (score 0):

There are no skin weights on the plane so that would need to be fixed. The weight painting will take some time to do since you need to do it by hand.

Also, you need to have much higher resolution on your mesh so it can deform properly and more bones to follow the curve to give a convincing result.

As a side note: It might be easier to solve this with a curve deformer directly attached to the mesh but I guess that you have reasons of doing this with bones.

Comment: I'm going to do the following as you said and hope for better result. As far as your side note is concerned, I have solved this animation in the way that curve modifier was directly attached to the mesh, but I'm using blender exporter which exports only mesh animations using bones and this are my restrictions.